# What the standard/conventional extension for a one data per line file on Windows? (list)

Tags: file, naming-conventions, file-extension

I'm used to name list files (one item per line) as `*.lst` under Linux.

Example.:

*\data.lst*

```
entry1
entry2
entry3
...
entryN
```

However i am currently working on Windows with Visual Studio, and `*.lst` file is recognized as [MASM Listing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/microsoft-macro-assembler-reference?view=msvc-170) (*Microsoft Macro Assembler*) which could be a security risk. 
This problem was very easy to solve by just changing it to `*.list, *.txt, etc..`. But raised this question that i could not find an answer for. 
Is there a standard/conventional extension to use on this type of file?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use the file suffix `.txt`. However, you could also view the file as a one-column [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file and in that case you can use the suffix `.csv`.